# Siegel set in SO(n,1) modulo integer points?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

I wonder what is known about a fundamental region for SO($n,1$) modulo its integer points? is there only one cusp? and if one writes a Siegel set in the form of 
$K A_\tau N_c$, where $N_c$ is compact and $A_\tau$ is the set of elements diag$(a,1,...,1,1/a)$  for  $a < \tau$,  then what is an estimate for $\tau$? in SL$_n$ one has $2/\sqrt{3}$, will it work for SO$(n,1)$ for any $n$?
Any reference will be appreciated. Maybe even a precise  fundamental domain in $H^n$ is known for this example? then it should not be difficult to see how big a Siegel set needs to be to contain this fundamental domain...

Comment: I would suggest looking at Chapter 28 of sphere packings lattices and groups:
http://books.google.com/books?id=upYwZ6cQumoC&lpg=PP1&dq=sphere%20packings%20lattices%20and%20group&pg=PR73#v=onepage&q&f=false



Comment: The number of cusps is the number of Euclidean unimodular lattices of dimension $n-1$, which grows quite rapidly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_lattice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of cusps could be more than 1, see [here](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/areid/allflat_new.pdf), remark on page 294.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that. And yet I wonder, when there is only one cusp, can one say anything about a bound for $\tau$?